Problem with Removing Autofocus Border on iPhone in CSS
problem-img
When I try to select multiple options, I encounter an issue specifically on iPhones. When I click on multiple choices, some of the options appear to overflow, with parts of them remaining visible on both the left and right sides of the screen.I tried using :focus and :focus:auto to fix the issue, but it's not working.
<Form.Check
  className="optionradiobtn"
  style={{
    width: '95%',
    '--button-color': borderColor,
  }}
  inline
  checked={
    isMultipleselect[option.questionid] &&
    isMultipleselect[option.questionid][ansIndex]
  }
  onChange={() => {
    handelGetMcqValue(
      QuestionNumber,
      answer,
      option.questionid,
      ansIndex,
      option.multiple_answer
    );
  }}
  name={`group1-${QuestionNumber}`}
  type={option.multiple_answer === '1' ? 'checkbox' : 'radio'}
/>


I feel like your code is too limited to help you or to even illustrate the issue. At least provide what you have tried (the focus you mentioned) and didn't work, so we can see what you are trying to do.

First, thank you for taking the time to attend to my issue. I’m providing you with the link to a survey for the bug. In all MCQs, the black border around the options doesn't disappear when trying to select multiple choices. This bug only appears on iPhone devices, so you can check it there.
Link:  https://app.surveyslack.com/surveyform/51718
